# req.headers.cookie is undefined

Tags: node.js, express

Whenever I run my program, this happens:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at /home/runner/Factions-Online-Multiplayer-Clicker-Game/index.js:28:49
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/runner/Factions-Online-Multiplayer-Clicker-Game/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/runner/Factions-Online-Multiplayer-Clicker-Game/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/runner/Factions-Online-Multiplayer-Clicker-Game/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/runner/Factions-Online-Multiplayer-Clicker-Game/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/runner/Factions-Online-Multiplayer-Clicker-Game/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/runner/Factions-Online-Multiplayer-Clicker-Game/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/runner/Factions-Online-Multiplayer-Clicker-Game/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (/home/runner/Factions-Online-Multiplayer-Clicker-Game/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/runner/Factions-Online-Multiplayer-Clicker-Game/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

I've done this before, but I'm not sure why it returns this. The code where the error happens is below.

```js
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  var cookies = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie.toString());
  var accounts = loadjson('passwords.json');
  if (cookies.username && cookies.password) {
    if (cookies.username in accounts) {
      if (accounts[cookies.username] === sha256(cookies.password)) {
        res.render("html/game")
      } else {
        res.render("html/index");
      }
    } else {
      res.render("html/index");
    }
  } else {
    res.render("html/index");
  }
});
```

[The full program is here](https://repl.it/@CatR3kd/Factions-Online-Multiplayer-Clicker-Game#index.js).

Comment: have you used cookie-parser? http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html

Comment: You can't be sure that the client will send a `Cookie` header, so you always have to check if it exists or not.

Comment: @Max That sadly does nothing (in my case at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `cookie-parser` package as a middleware it returns cookie in `req.cookies` object rather than `req.headers.cookie`.

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  var cookies = cookie.parse(req.cookies.toString());
  //... Rest of the code
  }
```

Read more about it [here](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser#cookieparsersecret-options)